# Bootstrap labels are not wrapped in the DIV?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap labels are not being wrapped in my DIV as expected? They just keep going off the screen? Does anyone have any idea why?  I have included a screenshot, and the code is below:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-right form-inline">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divParkingArea" class="form-group">
                <label>Parking Area:</label><br />
                <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddParkingArea" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
                     <option selected="selected" value="7">Test Parking Area XXX</option>
                     <option value="5">Tower A Parking</option>
                     <option value="6">Tower B Parking</option>

                </select>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_parkingAreaOverview" style="width:600px;"><h3>Level 2</h3><hr><span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 22</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 33</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 44</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 55</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 66</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 77</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 88</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 111</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 222</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 333</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 444</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 555</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 666</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 777</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 888</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 999</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 000</span><br /><br /><br /><h3>Level 1</h3><hr><span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 4</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 5</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 7</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 8</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 9</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 10</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 12</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 13</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 14</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 15</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Why is it acting like this]

Hope you can give me a hint! Thanks!

Regards,

Bob

EDIT:

1) removed the &nbsp as suggested, and it worked fine! But...

2) Added margin-top and margin-right to get some space, and a popup to some of the labels, and now the results look the same again? See below:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-right form-inline">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divParkingArea" class="form-group">
                <label>Parking Area:</label><br />
                <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddParkingArea" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
<option selected="selected" value="7">Test Parking Area XXX</option>
<option value="5">Tower A Parking</option>
<option value="6">Tower B Parking</option>

</select>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_parkingAreaOverview"><h3>Level 2</h3><hr><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 22</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 33</span><span class="label label-default" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px; color:#000;"><a style="color:#fff;" href="#" id="slotPopup199" data-toggle="popover" title="SlotSlotSlotSlot 44" data-content="Connected to: Tower A, 1022B (10F)">SlotSlotSlotSlot 44</a></span><span class="label label-default" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px; color:#000;"><a style="color:#fff;" href="#" id="slotPopup200" data-toggle="popover" title="SlotSlotSlotSlot 55" data-content="Connected to: Tower A, 1022B (10F)">SlotSlotSlotSlot 55</a></span><span class="label label-default" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px; color:#000;"><a style="color:#fff;" href="#" id="slotPopup201" data-toggle="popover" title="SlotSlotSlotSlot 66" data-content="Connected to: Tower A, 1022B (10F)">SlotSlotSlotSlot 66</a></span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 77</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 88</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 99</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 111</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 222</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 333</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 444</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 555</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 666</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 777</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 888</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 999</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 000</span><br /><br /><br /><h3>Level 1</h3><hr><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 1</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 2</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 3</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 4</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 5</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 6</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 7</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 8</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 9</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 10</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 12</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 13</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 14</span><span class="label label-success" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">SlotSlotSlotSlot 15</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your container doesn't seemed to be closed.

Comment: I dont see any open containers?

Comment: `<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">` is not being closed after the second row.

Comment: Sorry, it is. I just missed it in the cut and paste:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of your use of `&nbsp;`, it is all read as one line. You should replace them with regular spaces and use css margins if you need additional space in between each item.

```
<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 22</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 33</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 44</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 55</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 66</span> <span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 77</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5ME3/

By definition, non-breaking spaces **prevent line breaks**.

> (&nbsp), is a variant of the space character that prevents an **automatic line break (line wrap)** at its position

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: Worked! However, When I added a margin-right and margin-top, to get some space, and a botostrap popover, then the results are back to what it was before? Please have a look at the edit..

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `&nbsp` as you do if you don't want to mess with adding css styles, but you have to set "`word-wrap:break-word`" at the parent DIV style as follows

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-right form-inline">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divParkingArea" class="form-group">
                <label>Parking Area:</label><br />
                <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddParkingArea\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddParkingArea" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
                     <option selected="selected" value="7">Test Parking Area XXX</option>
                     <option value="5">Tower A Parking</option>
                     <option value="6">Tower B Parking</option>

                </select>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_parkingAreaOverview" style="width:600px;word-wrap:break-word"><h3>Level 2</h3><hr><span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 22</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 33</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 44</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 55</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 66</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 77</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 88</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 111</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 222</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 333</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 444</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 555</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 666</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 777</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 888</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 999</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 000</span><br /><br /><br /><h3>Level 1</h3><hr><span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 4</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 5</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 7</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 8</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 9</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 10</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 11</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 12</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 13</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 14</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-success">SlotSlotSlotSlot 15</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```